# Git branch split point

Tags: git, git-branch

I am having issues cleaning up my git history tree..

Basically my git repository with 1 branch looks like:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--Z--X--Y...   master
          \
           F--G--H--I--J--K--L...       branch1
```

That commit E is some not-important changes and can be made redundant.
The correct split point here should be I not D.
That commit E can be either removed or added to both branches..

Is there any way this can be achieved?

----- **Update**

Wow thank you very much for all your help!
I have tried what torek suggested and it worked like a charm!

Now.. I have another repository to clean but it is more complicated..

It looks like:

```
1--2--3--4--*A--5--6--7--8--*B--9--10--11--*C--*D--12--13--14            master
          \ 
           5--6--7--8--9--10--11--12--13--14                             branch1
```

note1: the letters represent the content of the commit
note2: * *letter* commits are only for master branch

Is there a way to clean up a history tree like this?

Also, what is the recommended git method for projects structured like this?
i.e after branching, most of the commits will contain the same updates except some branch specific commits

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, +1 on the question for drawing the commit graph. :-)  Second, not terribly important but you should probably think of this as two branches, `master` and `branch1`.  There's nothing special about `master`, it's just a branch like any other.<sup>1</sup>

Now, central to everything in git is the fact that you can never change a commit.  This comes about from the way git actually names each commit,<sup>2</sup> using the big ugly 40-character SHA-1: the SHA-1 is made by computing a cryptographic checksum of the *contents* of the commit.  So if you (try to) change anything, the "true name" changes, and you have a new and different commit.

Instead, what you can do is *copy* an old commit to a new one, making the desired changes along the way just before the commit gets finalized (and hence given its "true name").  What we'll do here is make copies.

You drew this graph:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--Z--X--Y...   master
          \
           F--G--H--I--J--K--L...       branch1
```

but that can't quite be right, because each commit points back to its parent commit,<sup>3</sup> and here `F` points back to `E` when we look at `master`, but `F` points back to `D` when we look at `branch1`.  (I'm assuming here that each single letter stands in for the SHA-1 "true name" of a given commit.)  I'm going to assume that the ones currently on `branch1` are the copies, though it doesn't really matter which, as long as you're happy with the trees associated with those commits (i.e., what you get when you `git checkout` one of them).

What you want looks like this:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--Z--X--Y...   master
                         \
                          J'-K'-L'...   branch1
```

Here the "prime" mark in `J'`, `K'`, and `L'` indicate that these are copies of commits `J`, `K`, and `L`.

While I've been writing this answer, a few have proposed using `git cherry-pick` to make these copies.  That works just fine—but in fact, we can use `git rebase` to do the trick, because where `cherry-pick` is a simple axe you can use to cut down one cherry tree, `rebase` is a fully automated chain-saw you can use to do them all in one swoop.

We start by telling `rebase` to operate on `branch1`; the easy way is to `git checkout branch1` (or we could just add `branch1` as a final argument to `git rebase`, but I'll use the "easy way").

Next, we need to know where we want the commits to branch off of, i.e., have some way to name commit `I`.  From the above, we might be able to say `master~3`: count back four commits from `master` (which names commit `Y`) and you step through `X`, then `Z`, then reach `I`.  Or you can do it by the true-name SHA-1, which always works but often requires cut-and-paste to get right.  For the command below, I'll just write *`I`*.  We'll tell rebase to base `--onto` that commit.

Finally, we need to get `rebase` to pick commits `J`, `K`, and `L` to copy.  There are a bunch of ways to do this as well.  Perhaps the easiest is to use `git rebase -i`, which will offer to rebase everything on `branch1`, and then you can delete the `pick` lines for the first four commits.  Or, we can tell `rebase` to exclude particular commits, but I'll assume you'll use the interactive method.

Thus, the final command here is `git rebase -i --onto I master` (after doing the `git checkout branch1` command).  The `-i` makes this interactive, so that you can drop commits; the `--onto` selects the target for the new series of commits that `rebase` will cherry-pick; and the `master` part tells `rebase` which commits to exclude: specifically, any commits reachable from the name `master`.  (This excludes commits `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`, but not the copied versions `F'`, `G'`, `H'`, and `I'` that appear on `branch`: you'll just delete the "pick" lines for those).

After `git rebase` finishes its series of `git cherry-pick` commands, the last thing it does is move the branch label for your current branch (`branch1`) to the tip-most new commit.  So this does produce:

```
A--B--C--D--E--F--G--H--I--Z--X--Y...   master
                         \
                          J'-K'-L'...   branch1
```

provided that all goes well.  (If it goes badly, you can `git rebase --abort` to stop the process and put everything back the way it was before you started.)

---

We could be fancier and (assuming `I'` is `branch1~3`) do:

```
git rebase --onto master~3 branch1~3 branch1
```

without even any initial `git checkout`, but this assumes that counting back 3 is correct here (for both `master` and `branch1`).  This is basically the same as before, with three modifications:

1. we add `branch1` on the end to make `rebase` check it out as a first step
2. we use `branch1~3` instead of `master` as the argument that says "exclude this stuff, only rebase stuff that's not reachable from here"
3. we drop the `-i` since we don't need to edit away "pick" commands this time

This requires a bit more careful counting of commits to make sure all the `~` expressions are right (or, again, you can work this by raw SHA-1 IDs).

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, there are a few special things about `master`: for one, it's the branch you're put on when you do `git init` and it creates a new repository.  The other is that `git merge` tweaks the merge message slightly.  But both of these are pretty trivial.

<sup>2</sup>This is actually true of all four of the kinds of objects found in a git repository (commit, tree, annotated tag, and "blob"—the last one stores file contents).  Each is stored in the repository and then given a name that consists of its own cryptographic checksum.

<sup>3</sup>More precisely, each commit has zero or more `parent ...` lines in it, with each `parent` giving the SHA-1 ID of the corresponding parent commit.  The first parent is generally the "main line" of a branch, and any additional parents indicate that this is a merge commit.  A commit with no parents, like `A` above, is a "root commit".

Comment: Why not just `git checkout branch1` followed by `git rebase COMMIT_HASH_FOR_I`?  Or just `git rebase COMMIT_HASH_FOR_I branch1`? (`COMMIT_HASH_FOR_I` is for the version in master)  I think it's a little more direct that way, though your version is the full, canonical form. :-)  Nice answer, BTW.  Very complete.

Comment: @jszakmeister: I haven't tried it, but I think (assuming the original graph should read `F'-G'-H'-I'-...` a simple `git rebase <sha1-for-I>` will attempt to re-copy `F'` to `F''`, etc., and be unable to see that they're already in.  Rebase does know to drop identical commits in some cases, so it might work.

Comment: As long as the diff is the same, then the patch id will be too, and Git will definitely drop them.  It only becomes a problem if `F'`, `G'`, and `H'` have additional modifications due to conflict or being amended in some way.  FWIW, I've done this more than a few times. :-)

Comment: @jszakmeister: ah, come to think of it, I *have* done this before, and yes, it works fine in most cases.  Obviously I have not tried it on hoistyler's code though :-)

Answer (score 2):

You could make a new branch at `I` and [cherry pick](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) all changes made in `branch1` so basically

```
 git branch -b temp I
 git cherry-pick J..branch1
```

You will then have a new branch `temp` split at `I` without the changes of `E` and containing all commits of `branch1`  starting with `J` if that worked correctly you can rename the two to make the `temp` branch your new `branch1`. Before cherry picking you can revert commit E if you don't want it in  `branch1`

Comment: I'll just change your first command and replace it by this one: `git checkout -b temp I`. By using this command you'll be automatically on the appropriate branch to execute the next provided commands.

Comment: This solution seems now to be a good way to solve the described problem of branch starting point but the `git revert E`is not what @hoistyler is asking for! This command will create a new commit that will be identical to E and the modifications of F, G and H will be lost!

Comment: Misunderstood the question slightly sorry

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this, is to create a new branch as a copy of master and do `git reset --hard I-commit` and then `cherry-pick` the commits you want (hoping there are not too many)

Comment: In my opinion it's better to create directly a new branch starting from I instead of making such kind of reset command.